# Is there any relationship between 田 (tián), 由 (yóu), 甲 (jiǎ), and 申 (shēn)?

Tags: characters

**Question**: Is there any relationship between 田, 由, 甲, and 申?

- [田](http://dict.cn/%E7%94%B0) (tián) = field; it seems rarely used
- [由](http://dict.cn/%E7%94%B1) (yóu) = ???; I've only seen it as a radical for [油](http://dict.cn/%E6%B2%B9) (yóu) = oil
- [甲](http://dict.cn/%E7%94%B2) (jiǎ) = nails, as in fingernails [手指甲](http://dict.cn/%E6%89%8B%E6%8C%87%E7%94%B2) (shǒuzhǐjiǎ); it's also a radical in 鸭子 (yāzi) = duck
- [申](http://dict.cn/%E7%94%B3) (shēn) = ???; I've seen it used in 申请 (shēnqǐng) = application

The characters appear similar, so I tend to get them confused often.  It might be there's a reason these characters are similar which might help me remember them better (or there might be no meaningful relationship).

Comment: cf。日加一笔可以变成什么字？https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/177588211.html

Comment: don't see modern glyph, we should see original glyph instead. enter your characters at   http://www.zdic.net/z/1f/zy/7531.htm  to check the most ancient glyph.

Comment: No meaningful relationship. 由 is contentious in its meaning. The upper surrounding box in 甲 was a Shang king royalty mark (the character 甲 was almost identical in shape to the ancient 七 and modern 十 without the box), and without this box it was a picture of *marks on split bark/outer seed coatings* > *hard outer coating* > *nail, armour*. 申 is the original character for 电 (**/\*lˤi[n]-s/**), and depicts *forked lightning*; the meaning *extend* (**/\*l̥i[n]/**) is a semantic extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The origin of 田 was a pictograph of a rice field
>
> http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/zy/7530.htm [image: rice field]
>
> The primary meaning of 田 is 'rice **field**'

~

> The origin of 由 was a pictograph of a sprout
>
> http://www.zdic.net/z/1f/zy/7531.htm [image: oil lamp]
>
> The primary meaning of 由 is '**from**; begin with'

~

> The origin of 甲 was a pictograph of the intersection of a [planted armor](http://battle-ready.com/home/wp-content/uploads/armour_short_plateD_1.jpg)
>
> http://www.zdic.net/z/1f/zy/7532.htm [image: planted armor]
>
> The primary meaning of 甲 is '**armor**; top class'

~

> The origin of 申 was a pictograph of a man kneeing with pleading hands (to plead to gods)
>
> http://www.zdic.net/z/1f/zy/7533.htm [image: man kneeing with pleading hands]
>
> The primary meaning of 申 is '**plead**'

Answer (score 0):

They are not related.

In Oracle bone script, they are completely different shapes.